# Is the circle a vector-valued function?

Tags: calculus, vectors, circles

I know the circle is not representable by a function $f: \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$.

However, if I take the vector function $F(t) = (\sin{t}, \cos{t})$, can that be considered the function of a circle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can. Sometimes we call your function $F\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ given by
$$F(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$$
a parametrisation of the circle. It is a vector-valued function, whose image is the circle.